# when adding new text it appears on bottom and rest of text goes up

Tags: text, scroll, pygame, display, bottom-up

I want to display text on the text box that says if I hit and how much damage I do and vice versa for the enemy, but I just can't figure out how to make the text to display in this manner.

Here is the code I'm working on:

```py
def textBox(textv):
    lText = []
    text = font.render(str(textv),True,(1,1,1))
    lText.append(text)
    if len(lText) >= 10:
        lText.pop(9)
    screen.blit(lText[0],(20,400))
    screen.blit(lText[1],(20,380))

while True:

    battle_screen()
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(enemy_background,(20,20))
    player.drawPlayer()
    enemy.newEnemy()
    textBox("Daniel")
    textBox("Jenny")
    
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: How can i add a new text under the old text and move the old text up?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rendere the text an add the rendered text into a list:

```py
text_surf_list = []
text_surf = font.render("Daniel", True, (255, 255, 0))
text_surf_list.append(text_surf)
text_surf = font.render("Jenny", True, (255, 255, 0))
text_surf_list.append(text_surf)
```

Define a rectangular area for the text box:

```py
text_box_rect = pygame.Rect(20, 20, 250, 360)
```

Iterate through list in [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) order. Draw the text from the bottom up. Remove the text from the list if it is not in the box (see [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)):

```py
text_y = box_rect.bottom - font.get_height()
for text_surf in reversed(text_surf_list[:]):
    if text_y <= box_rect.top: 
        text_surf_list.remove(text_surf)
    else:
        surf.blit(text_surf, (box_rect.left + 10, text_y))
    text_y -= font.get_height()
```

Set a temporary clipping area while drawing the text box with[pygame.Surface.set_clip](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_clip):

```py
# set clipping
surf.set_clip(box_rect)

# draw text box
# [...]

# disable clipping
surf.set_clip(None)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame, random

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def draw_scroll_text_box(surf, font, box_rect, text_surf_list):
    surf.set_clip(box_rect)
    text_y = box_rect.bottom - font.get_height() - 10
    for text_surf in reversed(text_surf_list[:]):
        if text_y <= box_rect.top: 
            text_surf_list.remove(text_surf)
        else:
            surf.blit(text_surf, (box_rect.left + 10, text_y))
        text_y -= font.get_height()
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, (164, 164, 164), box_rect, 5)
    surf.set_clip(None)

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)
text_box_rect = pygame.Rect(20, 20, 250, 360)
text_surf_list = []
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, 200)

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *background.get_size(), (32, 32, 32), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
[pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect) for rect, color in tiles]

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 
        if event.type == timer_event:
            names = ["Daniel", "Jenny", "Patrick", "Sandy", "Bob"]
            text_surf = font.render(random.choice(names), True, (255, 255, 0))
            text_surf_list.append(text_surf)

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    draw_scroll_text_box(window, font, text_box_rect, text_surf_list)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you